# Facebook share button and ajax generated content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, dom

Ok, I'm a little at a lost. I am trying to share a page on Facebook which is a picture gallery. I have a unique url which can tell the gallery which thumbnail is current and it will load up the image correctly. This unique URL prompts an ajax script to display all the HTML necessary.

The problem is when Facebook scans the HTML to determine a photo to use for my live stream it finds absolutely nothing, it just sees some javascript and that's really about it.

Unfortunately I have zero access or ability to modify anything on this page other then simple settings which relate nothing to this issue. Though I CAN run PHP on this server with whatever PHP pages I upload. Is there ANYTHING I can do to help Facebook understand the page being shared and see HTML in much the same way if I inspected an element on my browser?

I thought about a PHP script which could screen scrape the HTML but I don't even know if that would work. Idea's? Suggestion? Should I just admit defeat?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i understand exactly what you want, but if you want to parse facebook elements after loading a page with ajax, this may help you:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/